# Using the match method

Tags: java

The below makes it so that if it finds both the word hello, and goodbye in String text, it will print true. My question is: Can you make it print something else? If so how? I want to make it print "Yes" as oppose to "True".

```
String text = "I said hello, and goodbye." 
System.out.println(text.matches("(?i)^.*\\bhello\\b.*\\bgoodbye\\b.*$"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a ternary statement?

```
([condition] ? [value-if-true] : [value-if-false])
```

For instance, if you wanted this to become "Yes"/"No":

```
(text.matches("(?i)^.*\\bhello\\b.*\\bgoodbye\\b.*$") ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Comment: I want to make it so that if it find both words in a sentence, no matter the order, it will print out yes if true and no if false. But it seems that this only check it in order. With hello at the start, and goodbye at the end. How do you make it so that it it does what I want it to do?

Comment: @nmelssx That, dear friend, is a different question than the one you asked above.

Comment: Do you have an answer for that? If you do, please tell me. Thanks.